# Null Response from SOAP API call in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, soap, angular6

I am making a simple soap call and trying to process the request. Here is my angular 6 component:

```
callSoap() {
const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://soapAPIURL.net/', true);
const sr =
    `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://soapAPIURL.net/ws" xmlns:com="http://soapAPIURL.com/common" xmlns:req="http://soapAPIURL.net/request">
      <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
          <ws:CreateUser>
            <com:Header>
              <com:User>1234</com:User>
            </com:Header>
              <req:Name>Test Name</req:Name>
          </ws:CreateUser>
          </soapenv:Body>
      </soapenv:Envelope>`;

}

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://soapAPIURL/CreateUser");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
xmlhttp.responseType = 'document';    

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange =  () => {
  console.log(xmlhttp);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            const xml = xmlhttp.responseXML;
            console.log(xml);
            console.log('Ok 200');
        }
    }
}

// Send the POST request.
xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

The first console.log prints out the xmlhttp request:

```
responseText: "", 
responseType: "",
status: 200,
responseXML: NULL,
response URL: (which I don't think is correct, its the same as my xmlhttp.open URL, my response Type is ''.
```

I am also getting a CORBS (Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response error).

Am I handling the response correctly?
Not sure if its a server side issue or client side issue? Could it be that I am calling this SOAP Api from my angular component?

Any direction would be great.

Comment: have you tried changing your content-type to 'application/xml'

Comment: Yes, no such luck...